# Interview ques database query prob

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
table no 1 Employee
Emp_ID | EMP_Name
1             | Sumit
2             | HR1
3             | sunny
4             | Bhupin
5             | Abhishek
6             |Lallan
7             | Ashi
8             | HR2
```

Table2 emp_hr:

```
Emp_ID | EMP_HR_ID
1             | 8
2             | NULL
3             | 2
5             | 4
6             | 4
7             | 2
8             | NULL
```

I want output as by sql server query, which comes automatically pointing name according to id stores in table 2 which have name stored in table 1:

```
Emp_Name       | HR
Sumit          | HR2
HR1            | Null
Sunny          | HR1
Abhishek       | Bhupin
Lallan         | Bhupin
Ashi           | HR1
HR2            | Null
```

Can anybody solve this query.

Comment: Can you please show your efforts?

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem yourself, or done any research to find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT A.EMP_NAME as name, C.EMP_NAME as HR
from EMP A
JOIN EMP_HR B ON A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID
LEFT JOIN EMP C on B.EMP_HR_ID = C.EMP_ID

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbf31/23

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to get your question or not, but i  guess this query can help you:

```
SELECT T2.EMP_Name Emp_Name,T3.EMP_Name HR FROM 
TABLE2 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 T2 
ON T1.Emp_ID = T2.Emp_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 T3 
ON T1.EMP_HR_ID= T3.Emp_ID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple join, the only slightly tricky part, is that you need to join to the same table twice, once to get the employee name, and once to get their Manager's name.

```
SELECT t1a.Emp_Name, t1b.Emp_Name AS HR
FROM Table2 t2
       JOIN Table1 t1a ON t1a.Emp_ID = t2.Emp_ID
  LEFT JOIN Table1 t1b ON t1b.Emp_ID = t2.EMP_HR_ID
```